# How to find an element with its text when it is under anchor tag in using selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

```
<a class="btn update" _ngcontent-c15="">Update</a>
```

This the element I need to identify.
Please help.

Comment: I am using WebElement updatebtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Update')]")); to identify this .

Comment: are you getting any error ?

Comment: yes,I was getting an error.it got solved I used: By.xpath("//a[@class='btn update']"). thanks for replying

Comment: @ayushkhare:Why you are not using linktext.  you can also use driver.findElement(By.linkText("Update")); or driver.findElement(By.linkText("Update")).click(); // to click the link

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention which language you are using. So I assume it's Java.

Since you don't have ID value, the simplest way is to find the element by the hyperlink test.

```
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Update"));
```

This will match the links in your page and get the link which has the text "Update" matching exactly.